# issue with Summer'19 release

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Guys I could see that the comfy and comfort views for lightning experience have been changed. If you could see the below screenshot I have use a lightning select in a modal popup(custom lightning component). The comfy view looks fine but the comfort view behaves a bit awkward. Can someone help me with your views on this and getting this corrected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `<lightning:inputField />` inside `<lightning:recordEditForm />` ?

According to the doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification), you can set the `density` attribute to `comfy` to display fields below their labels.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="OpportunityForm"
                          objectApiName="Opportunity"
                          density="comfy">

  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{! v.Opportunity.Name }"/>

  ...

</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked...

Comment: Glad to help, you can mark this as Accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

We also experienced the same issue. What it looks like - `<lightning:inputField />` now defaults to a horizontal layout (label on the left, field on the right).

Salesforce has not provided a variant attribute that can be passed into this component for the "stacked" view (label above input), but they have for other input components.

Since we don't have a variant attribute we are forced to use custom CSS to support stacked input at the moment.

```
Step 1 : Add a class "stacked-field" on the input field.

    <lightning:inputField class="stacked-field" />

Step 2 : Put following style in the component .css file.

  .vertical-field .slds-form-element_horizontal .slds-form-element__label {
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    float: none;
   }

  .vertical-field .slds-form-element_horizontal .slds-form-element__control {
    padding-left: 0;
   }
```